# Powershell - directreports -recurse

Tags: powershell

Although I know some basic Powershell stuff, I still find it hard to do some more advanced stuff, like using If statements etc.
I have a simple code to get the directReports of a manager:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {CN -eq "TestMngr"} -properties directReports | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty directreports |  
Get-ADUser -properties CN, DisplayName, Office, directReports |
Select-Object CN, DisplayName, Office, directReports
```

This code works fine and has the correct lay-out.
But now I want to also list the directReports of the first list of directReports, and so on...
I tried it with an If statement, but failed. Also tried with -recurse but also did not work. Also found some code somewhere online, but that was very complicated and did not work like I would.
Please help, thanks again :-)

Comment: Additional problem: When I export it to CSV, the directreports are shown as: **Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
$depth = 2
$UserCN = '<CN of User>'
$user = (Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -eq '$UserCN'").SamAccountName

$output = while ($depth -ge 1) {
    $temp = $user | Foreach-Object {
        Get-ADUser $_ -Properties CN,DirectReports | Where DirectReports |
            Select-Object -Property CN,DirectReports
    }
    $temp
    $user = $temp.DirectReports
    $depth--
}

$output |
    Select-Object CN,@{Name='DirectReports';Expression={
       ($_.DirectReports -replace 'CN=|,OU=.*|,DC=.*|\\') -join '; '}} |
           Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

**Explanation:**

`$depth` would be the number of recursions you want to perform. Currently, `$UserCN` holds the CN value of an AD user object. An initial query for that user is done to store a value in `$user` that can be passed into the `-Identity` parameter. The collection of `DirectReports` is joined by `;`, which you can change to whatever you want.

This currently does not output the `Get-ADUser` results for users who do not have a direct report. You can change that by removing the `Where DirectReports`.

Comment: I have added displayname and office in the properties and select-object, and that gives me the information needed.  Changing the `-Identity` to CN does not work, due to my lack of knowledge.   
However, it would be nice if the directReports would be shown as CN or displayname.  Also, is it possible to show the manager itself? Because it shows different layers, it would be nice to see the next layer. Thanks anyways!

Comment: unfortunately i get an error:  
`Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At line:7 char:20
+         Get-ADUser $_ -Properties CN,DirectReports | Where DirectRepo ...
+                    ~~`

Comment: Thanks very much, it works like I wanted! I have tweaked it a little bit to get the fields I need and posted that as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I finally use, thanks to @AdminOfThings.

```
$Manager = @{Name = "Manager"; Expression = {%{(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName}}}
$depth = 8
$UserCN = '<CN of User>'
$user = (Get-ADUser -Filter "CN -eq '$UserCN'").SamAccountName

$output = while ($depth -ge 1) {
    $temp = $user | Foreach-Object {
        Get-ADUser $_ -Properties CN, displayname, office, city, manager, DirectReports | 
            Select-Object -Property CN, displayname, office, city, Manager, DirectReports
    }
    $temp
    $user = $temp.DirectReports
    $depth--
}

$output |
    Select-Object CN, displayname, office, city, $Manager, @{Name='DirectReports';Expression={
       ($_.DirectReports -replace 'CN=|,OU=.*|,DC=.*|\\') -join '; '}} |
           Export-Csv -path C:Temp\Output.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoType
```